# when product out of stock single page show button notify woo-commerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

when product out of stock single page show notify woocommerce, i am doing this code but showing button only archive page, i want to show single page any one help for code
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EFd7.jpg

```
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'filter_loop_add_to_cart_link', 20, 3 );
 function filter_loop_add_to_cart_link( $button, $product, $args = array() ) {
 if( $product->is_in_stock() ) return $button;

// HERE set your button text (when product is not on stock)
$button_text = __('Not available', 'woocommerce');

 return sprintf( '<a class="button disabled" style="%s">%s</a>', $style, $button_text );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this into your single page product follow the below guide line.
I'm assuming you have copied the woocommerce template into your theme folder.
Navigate to the the path
yourtheme/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php
You can put your code here.

Comment: not work on this page function code

Comment: I didn't mean by put that code into that template. You need to put just the button with just the condition.